# Produce log file from Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How can I produce messages to the “logs” topic from a given log file using Python?

How to use the Fire-and-Forget approach for faster message delivery and send only error and warning messages for/with this?

Comment: Do these help? https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/ 
and
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-python-asyncio-integration/

Answer (score 0):

First, Python isn't required.

```
kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic logs < file.log
```

To do the same with kafka-python

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
with open('file.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        # not waiting for response, so fire and forget 
        producer.send('logs', line.rstrip())
producer.flush()
```

If you rerun either approach, it'll duplicate the file data, however, so this is why you'd use alternative tools for logs like Fluentd or Kafka Connect which can track which lines they've already consumed